# Name of special character selection feature of mobile keyboards

Tags: mobile, terminology

I am working on a application, for which I intend to suggest the use of a feature similar to what is used on most smartphones' keyboards to select special characters:

[image]

However, while it is easy to explain face-to-face, I feel that my report should have a better name for it than "that thing on your iPhone where you press a letter and other letters appear".

Is there a standard name for this feature?

Answer (score 1):

How about '**Special character selector**' or '**Alternate character grid**'?

When in doubt, just say 'the thingy you use to make letters like ę and ū show up.'

Answer (score 1):

It's an accented character selection, which is needed for most latin character based languages.  English is pretty unique in it's lack of accents (with the exception of adopted words).

So I would just refer to it as:

> **Accented character selector**

or

> Accented character overlay